# Unnamed/Nameless Pipes - maximum inactivity

Tags: c, pipe

i've been giving an assignment and i'm struggling with one of the requirements. 
My program works like this, i have an arbitrary numbers of child processes that communicate between then with several unnamed pipes. Let's say, i have the parent process, and that process is gonna create 3 process children. Children 1 and 2 communicate through unnamed pipe 1 while children 2 and 3 communicate through unnamed pipe 2. The problem is, whenever there isn't communication in one of the pipes for more than 10 seconds, i have to end all the processes. But i can't seem to reach a solution where i can check for activity in pipe 1 and in pipe 2. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

edit: one of the requirements is to implement this only using signals like alarm and handlers

Comment: `poll()`, `select()`, etc.

Comment: that was one of my first guesses, but we can't use those functions . everything needs to be implemented using alarms and handlers

Comment: You should mention a requirement like that in the question proper.

Comment: yes, i've edited it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using `popen()` and `pclose()`

```
FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);

int pclose(FILE *stream);
```

with the `type` value being: 'r' or 'w' for readonly or writeonly respectively.

Suggest reading the MAN page for all the details:

[popen](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

[pclose](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose)

You can use: `setitimer()` for timing intervals

```
int getitimer(int which, struct itimerval *curr_value);

int setitimer(int which, const struct itimerval *new_value,
                 struct itimerval *old_value);
```

[setitimer](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer)

[getitimer](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html)